# Proof in lambda calculus that 0 has no predecessor.

Tags: proof-writing, lambda-calculus

Using the following definitions

$0 := \lambda fx.x $

$suc := \lambda nfx.f \, (n \, f \, x)$

I am trying to proof that there exists no expression $a$, such that $suc \, a = 0$.

**First try:**

$suc \, a = (\lambda nfx.f \, (n \, f \, x)) \, a = \lambda fx.f \, (a \, f \, x) $

The expression $\lambda fx.f \, (a \, f \, x)$ is in $\beta$-normal form, as is $\lambda fx.x$ for $0$. Since both expressions are not identical (up to $\alpha$-equivalence), they are not equivalent. Therefore, no such $a$ exists. Is this sufficient to proof the statement?

**Second try:**

$suc \, a = 0$

$\lambda fx.f \, (a \, f \, x) = \lambda fx.x $

If they are equivalent, by extensionality, they should yield the same result when applied to the same parameters. Let's choose arbitrarily $g$ and $y$.

$(\lambda fx.f \, (a \, f \, x) ) \, g \, y = (\lambda fx.x) \, g \, y $

$g \, (a \, g \, y) = y $

As this must hold for all $g$ and $y$, let's choose an $z$ such that $z \neq y$ and pick $g=\lambda x.z$

$(\lambda x.z) \, (a \, (\lambda x.z) \, y) = y $

$z = y$

As we chose $z$ to be distinct from $y$, we found a contradiction, thus proofing that no such $a$ exists. Does this proof work?